# fillbetween causes Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)

Tags: pgfplots

This works beautifully:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
func(\x)=(\x<=0)*(1)    +
and(\x>0, \x<1)*(1) +
and(\x>=1, \x<=1.75)*(2)    +
and(\x>1.75, \x<3)*(1)  +
(\x>=3)*(0);
}
]
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0,   xmax=3,
ymin=0,   ymax=3,
ticks=none,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
xlabel=$t$, ylabel=$n_t$,
enlargelimits=false
]
\addplot[blue, domain=0:3, samples=200]{func(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

But if I uncomment the fifth line I get the `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>` error.
I'm using the `fillbetween` package in another part of the document that works fine.

Comment: No problem here. Perhaps you are using outdated packages?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Updated packages and everyting started working. Thanks a lot

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that was solved by updating some packages.

Comment: You're welcome. I guess we can then close this question (which is not a bad thing; it is just that the problem was too localized).

Comment: Yes, I will delete it.